# Flink Broadcast State Pattern: Avoiding inconsistency

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

In Flink [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/) we are warned that: "Order of events in Broadcast State may differ across tasks".

How can one implement an [application](https://flink.apache.org/2019/06/26/a-practical-guide-to-broadcast-state-in-apache-flink/#dynamic-pattern-evaluation-with-broadcast-state) with a **consistent** broadcast state across tasks, that allows deletes or updates (and not just additions)?

If order is not guaranteed then one task might get a "delete" event before it got a "create" event, or an "update" event that sets an old version after it got an event to set a new version.

Are there any measures one can take to minimize the out-of-order risk? (e.g. parallelism = 1, single Kafka partition etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the broadcast stream originates from an operator with a parallelism of 1, then this isn't an issue. It's only if your topology allows for race conditions among parallel broadcast streams that you have to worry about this.